# Unit testing timestamp field rule in firestore security rules

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am writing unit tests for my firestore security rules using the node.js library `@firebase/rules-unit-testing`

Here is my security rule for updating a document:

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid != null &&
  request.auth.uid == userId &&
  request.resource.data.updatedAt == request.time;
```

I want the `updatedAt` field to be always set to the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

In my unit test, I am trying to update the value with `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and verifying  that it should succeed. Here is my code snippet:

```
let testEnvironment: RulesTestEnvironment = await initializeTestEnvironment({
  projectId: PROJECT_ID,
  firestore: {
    rules: fs.readFileSync("../firestore.rules", "utf8"),
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080
  }
})

const firestore = testEnvironment.authenticatedContext("user_123").firestore()
const testDoc = firestore.doc("/writers/user_123")
await assertSucceeds(testDoc.update(
  "some_field", "some_value", "updatedAt", firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
))
```

In this case, `firestore.FieldValue` is not defined.

I tried using the admin SDK `firebase-admin`, changing the last statement to:

```
await assertSucceeds(testDoc.update(
  "some_field", "some_value", "updatedAt", admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
))
```

For this, I get the error-

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field updatedAt in document writers/user_123)

Can anyone suggest how to add tests for the timestamp field update?

Answer (score 0):

The data you pass is incorrectly formatted

Try this:

```
await assertSucceeds(testDoc.update(
  {some_field: "some_value", updatedAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()})
```

Comment: There are two overloads of the update method. One that you have suggested, other that I have used.  Check out [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update)

Comment: What to call using require if FieldValue is undefined?